# Не выводится программа на экран эмулятора в Android Studio 1.0

Tags: android-studio, android

Здравствуйте!

При запуске на выполнение программы в среде Android Studio 1.0 при помощи эмулятора программа не выводится на экран эмулятора.

Файл MainActivity.java самый простой, впервые созданный программой автоматически, как новый проект.

Пробовал создавать различные AVD с различными параметрами, не помогает.

Пробовал ставить отладочный вывод в окно LogCat.

Подскажите, в чем причина?

У меня на ПК оперативная память 2 Гб. Может, недостаточно оперативной памяти?

Ниже привожу содержимое файла AndroidManifest.xml, MainActivity.java и окон IDE Android Studio LogCat, Console, Grade Console.

---

Содержимое файла AndroidManifest.xml

---

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

```
package="ru.mbn.hellokitty" >

<application

    android:allowBackup="true"

    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"

    android:label="@string/app_name"

    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"

        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

</application>
```

</manifest>

---

Содержимое файла MainActivity.java

---

```
package ru.mbn.hellokitty;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import static android.util.Log.*;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Конструктор родительского класса
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Вывод отладочного сообщения
    Log.d("Hello Kitty", "Call onCreate() method for super class");

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Вывод отладочного сообщения
    Log.d("Hello Kitty", "Finished create user interface");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    // Вывод отладочного сообщения
    Log.d("Hello Kitty", "Finished create menu");

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    // Вывод отладочного сообщения
    Log.d("Hello Kitty", "Method onOptionsItemSelected()");

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

        // Вывод отладочного сообщения
        Log.d("Hello Kitty", "onOptionsItemSelected() return true");

        return true;
    }

    // Вывод отладочного сообщения
    Log.d("Hello Kitty", "onOptionsItemSelected() return super");

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

---

Содержимое окна LogCat

---

> 12-12 12:08:16.792 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty I/art﹕ Not
> late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
> 12-12 12:08:17.557 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty W/Zygote﹕
> Slow operation: 1367ms so far, now at
> Zygote.nativeForkAndSpecialize 12-12
> 12:08:17.653 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty W/Zygote﹕
> Slow operation: 1464ms so far, now at
> Zygote.postForkCommon 12-12
> 12:08:17.654 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty W/Zygote﹕
> Slow operation: 1472ms so far, now at
> zygoteConnection.runOnce:
> postForkAndSpecialize 12-12
> 12:08:19.370 
> 1208-1215/ru.mbn.hellokitty W/art﹕
> Suspending all threads took: 56.555ms
> 12-12 12:08:19.854 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> W/ActivityThread﹕ Application
> ru.mbn.hellokitty is waiting for the
> debugger on port 8100... 12-12
> 12:08:19.970 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ Sending WAIT chunk 12-12
> 12:08:20.081 
> 1208-1215/ru.mbn.hellokitty I/art﹕
> Debugger is active 12-12 12:08:20.182 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ Debugger has connected
> 12-12 12:08:20.183 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:20.440 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:20.664 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:20.869 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:21.073 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:21.275 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:21.504 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:21.722 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:21.932 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:22.134 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:22.341 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:22.577 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:22.799 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:23.100 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:23.339 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:23.549 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:23.771 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:23.982 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:24.184 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:24.385 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:24.599 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:24.802 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:25.019 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:25.230 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:25.450 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:25.659 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:25.879 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:26.082 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:26.350 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:26.559 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:26.760 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:26.962 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:27.245 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:27.463 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:27.665 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:27.867 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:28.069 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:28.271 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:28.473 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:28.676 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:28.883 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:29.087 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to
> settle... 12-12 12:08:29.306 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/System.out﹕ debugger has settled
> (1477) 12-12 12:08:29.917 
> 1208-1215/ru.mbn.hellokitty W/art﹕
> Suspending all threads took: 101.511ms
> 12-12 12:08:30.874 
> 1208-1215/ru.mbn.hellokitty W/art﹕
> Suspending all threads took: 54.176ms
> 12-12 12:08:31.332 
> 1208-1215/ru.mbn.hellokitty W/art﹕
> Suspending all threads took: 14.171ms
> 12-12 12:08:31.428 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty D/Hello
> Kitty﹕ Call onCreate() method for
> super class 12-12 12:08:31.840 
> 1208-1220/ru.mbn.hellokitty I/art﹕
> Background sticky concurrent mark
> sweep GC freed 1929(131KB) AllocSpace
> objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 29% free,
> 438KB/623KB, paused 3.919ms total
> 701.447ms 12-12 12:08:31.862    1208-1220/ru.mbn.hellokitty W/art﹕
> Suspending all threads took: 19.576ms
> 12-12 12:08:32.415 
> 1208-1215/ru.mbn.hellokitty W/art﹕
> Suspending all threads took: 90.144ms
> 12-12 12:08:32.943 
> 1208-1215/ru.mbn.hellokitty W/art﹕
> Suspending all threads took: 100.868ms
> 12-12 12:08:33.835 
> 1208-1215/ru.mbn.hellokitty W/art﹕
> Suspending all threads took: 460.711ms
> 12-12 12:08:33.884 
> 1208-1220/ru.mbn.hellokitty I/art﹕
> Background partial concurrent mark
> sweep GC freed 146(51KB) AllocSpace
> objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 51% free,
> 476KB/988KB, paused 6.787ms total
> 899.954ms 12-12 12:08:33.921    1208-1220/ru.mbn.hellokitty W/art﹕
> Suspending all threads took: 36.816ms
> 12-12 12:08:34.452 
> 1208-1215/ru.mbn.hellokitty W/art﹕
> Suspending all threads took: 117.232ms
> 12-12 12:08:35.326 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty D/Hello
> Kitty﹕ Finished create user interface
> 12-12 12:08:35.871 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 115 frames! 
> The application may be doing too much
> work on its main thread. 12-12
> 12:08:36.886 
> 1208-1215/ru.mbn.hellokitty W/art﹕
> Suspending all threads took: 36.876ms
> 12-12 12:08:37.452 
> 1208-1220/ru.mbn.hellokitty I/art﹕
> Background sticky concurrent mark
> sweep GC freed 1214(116KB) AllocSpace
> objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 23% free,
> 759KB/988KB, paused 2.247ms total
> 278.011ms 12-12 12:08:37.461    1208-1220/ru.mbn.hellokitty W/art﹕
> Suspending all threads took: 7.470ms
> 12-12 12:08:37.613 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty D/Hello
> Kitty﹕ Finished create menu 12-12
> 12:08:37.847 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 1759 frames! 
> The application may be doing too much
> work on its main thread. 12-12
> 12:08:37.886 
> 1208-1215/ru.mbn.hellokitty W/art﹕
> Suspending all threads took: 19.996ms
> 12-12 12:08:38.188 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> D/gralloc_goldfish﹕ Emulator without
> GPU emulation detected. 12-12
> 12:08:38.582 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 158 frames! 
> The application may be doing too much
> work on its main thread. 12-12
> 12:09:13.714 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty D/Hello
> Kitty﹕ Call onCreate() method for
> super class 12-12 12:09:13.900 
> 1208-1220/ru.mbn.hellokitty W/art﹕
> Suspending all threads took: 10.581ms
> 12-12 12:09:13.933 
> 1208-1220/ru.mbn.hellokitty I/art﹕
> Background sticky concurrent mark
> sweep GC freed 627(27KB) AllocSpace
> objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 14% free,
> 849KB/988KB, paused 14.009ms total
> 122.612ms 12-12 12:09:13.999    1208-1215/ru.mbn.hellokitty W/art﹕
> Suspending all threads took: 11.857ms
> 12-12 12:09:14.041 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty D/Hello
> Kitty﹕ Finished create user interface
> 12-12 12:09:14.389 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 12803 frames!
> The application may be doing too much
> work on its main thread. 12-12
> 12:09:14.645 
> 1208-1215/ru.mbn.hellokitty W/art﹕
> Suspending all threads took: 153.416ms
> 12-12 12:09:14.868 
> 1208-1220/ru.mbn.hellokitty I/art﹕
> Background partial concurrent mark
> sweep GC freed 221(22KB) AllocSpace
> objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 37% free,
> 843KB/1355KB, paused 1.901ms total
> 463.659ms 12-12 12:09:15.012    1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty D/Hello
> Kitty﹕ Finished create menu 12-12
> 12:09:15.017 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 225 frames! 
> The application may be doing too much
> work on its main thread. 12-12
> 12:09:15.290 
> 1208-1208/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 124 frames! 
> The application may be doing too much
> work on its main thread. 12-12
> 12:09:23.098 
> 1208-1215/ru.mbn.hellokitty W/art﹕
> Suspending all threads took: 90.729ms
> 12-12 12:09:56.649 
> 1208-1215/ru.mbn.hellokitty W/art﹕
> Suspending all threads took: 10.560ms
> 12-12 12:09:58.248 
> 1208-1215/ru.mbn.hellokitty W/art﹕
> Suspending all threads took: 15.606ms
> 12-12 12:10:09.318 
> 1208-1215/ru.mbn.hellokitty W/art﹕
> Suspending all threads took: 9.810ms
> 12-12 12:10:17.238 
> 1208-1215/ru.mbn.hellokitty W/art﹕
> Suspending all threads took: 60.784ms
> 12-12 12:11:12.485 
> 1208-1215/ru.mbn.hellokitty W/art﹕
> Suspending all threads took: 67.197ms

---

Содержимое окна Console

---

> Waiting for device.
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe
> -avd 2_7_QVGA_API_21_5_0_1_arm -netspeed full -netdelay none Device connected: emulator-5554 Device
> 2_7_QVGA_API_21_5_0_1_arm
> [emulator-5554] is online, waiting for
> processes to start up.. Device
> 2_7_QVGA_API_21_5_0_1_arm
> [emulator-5554] is online, waiting for
> processes to start up.. Device
> 2_7_QVGA_API_21_5_0_1_arm
> [emulator-5554] is online, waiting for
> processes to start up.. Device is
> ready: 2_7_QVGA_API_21_5_0_1_arm
> [emulator-5554] Target device:
> 2_7_QVGA_API_21_5_0_1_arm
> [emulator-5554] Uploading file    local
> path:
> C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\HelloKitty\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
>   remote path:
> /data/local/tmp/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> Installing ru.mbn.hellokitty DEVICE
> SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r
> "/data/local/tmp/ru.mbn.hellokitty"
> pkg: /data/local/tmp/ru.mbn.hellokitty
> Success
>
> Launching application:
> ru.mbn.hellokitty/ru.mbn.hellokitty.MainActivity.
> DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -D -n
> "ru.mbn.hellokitty/ru.mbn.hellokitty.MainActivity"
> -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
> Starting: Intent {
> act=android.intent.action.MAIN
> cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]
> cmp=ru.mbn.hellokitty/.MainActivity }
>
> Waiting for process: ru.mbn.hellokitty
> Connected to the target VM, address:
> 'localhost:8621', transport: 'socket'
> Disconnected from the target VM,
> address: 'localhost:8621', transport:
> 'socket'

---

Содержимое окна Grade Console

---

> Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
>
> Configuration on demand is an
> incubating feature. :app:preBuild
> :app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
> :app:preDebugBuild
> :app:checkDebugManifest
> :app:preReleaseBuild
> :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72102Library
> UP-TO-DATE
> :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42102Library
> UP-TO-DATE
> :app:prepareDebugDependencies
> :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
> :app:compileDebugRenderscript
> UP-TO-DATE
> :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
> UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugAssets
> UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugAssets
> UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugResValues
> UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugResources
> UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugResources
> UP-TO-DATE :app:processDebugManifest
> UP-TO-DATE :app:processDebugResources
> UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugSources
> UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugJava
> UP-TO-DATE :app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> :app:dexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> :app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
> :app:validateDebugSigning
> :app:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
> :app:zipalignDebug UP-TO-DATE
> :app:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL
>
> Total time: 22.603 secs

Comment: У меня тоже такая проблема тут проблема не в оперативке.У меня 6 ГБ оперативки все запустится всё в норме но только проект который я создаль в эмуляторе не показывается.Тут проблема в чем то другом.В каких то настройках!

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, не нужно сюда выкидывать простыню логов из LogCat`а - отфильтруйте ее либо вручную, либо по RegExp.

Android Studio является очень "жирной" IDE, в которой совмещаются много тулз, поэтому в оперативной памяти она занимает, в среднем, 1гб места. Делайте выводы насчет своих 2 гб ОЗУ.

Эмулятор может не работать по нескольким причинам: либо вы просто выкачали не все, что для его работы необходимо (из SDK Manager`а), либо же неправильно настроили. В таком случае, разумеется, на эмуляторе Android не запустится (хотя сам эмулятор запустится).

---

**UPD**

Судя по вашим логам, приложение успешно скомпилировалось и подготовлено к запуску на устройстве. Покажите свой файл манифеста приложения и убедитесь, что в настройках проекта стоит запуск НУЖНОЙ активности после сборки приложения на устройстве.

Об успешной компиляции говорит вам система Gradle:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 22.603 secs
```

А о запуске - компилятор:

```
Launching application: ru.mbn.hellokitty/ru.mbn.hellokitty.MainActivity. 
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -D -n "ru.mbn.hellokitty/ru.mbn.hellokitty.MainActivity"
```

Comment: Да там, похоже, приложение стартует. Вот только памяти под эмулятор катастрофически не хватает. Вот оно и свопиться активно. А это накладывает свой отпечаток на скорость работы.

Comment: Действительно, если ОЗУ чересчур мало, то время будет такое, как в логах выше. Но, так или иначе, в конце концов приложение должно будет скомпилироваться и запуститься на виртуальном устройстве. Когда системе не хватает ОЗУ, задействовывается файл подкачки с жесткого диска - это в разы медленнее, но зато система не "умирает".

Answer (score 1):

Я бы тебе посоветовал использовать Genymotion, продукт бесплатный, качай с офф сайта, забудешь о проблемах с эмуляторами!

Answer (score 0):

Согласен с [[@0xFFh](/users/10774/0xffh)](/users/10774/0xffh).

Приложение компилируется нормально.
Studio в целом требует много ресурсов. У меня 4Гб оперативной памяти, и то испытываю дискомфорт от долгой загрузки эмулятора и компиляции проекта.

Предлагаю:

1. Закрыть все посторонние программы и попробовать подождать минут 10-15. 
   Чем меньше свободных ресурсов у вашего компьютера, тем медленнее "ворочается" Studio.
2. Проверить настройки Android Studio  и  эмулятора.
   Вот отличная [инструкция](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/9-urok-2-ustanovka-i-nastrojka-sredy-razrabotki.html) по настройке, лично мне помогла.